# convert a list(of ExpanoObject) to list of objects

Tags: vb.net, linq, expandoobject

I am trying to convert a list(of ExpanoObject) to list of objects with the code below

```
Dim li As List(Of ListItem) = items.Select(Of ExpandoObject)
    (Function(itm As ExpandoObject) 
     New ListItem(itm.Id, itm.Name, itm.Value)).ToList()
```

I got an error saying

> Id, Name , Value are not members of ExpandoObjects

ListItem is a static class with static properties Id, Name, Value

What can i do to fix the issue

Comment: You probably have to turn off `Option Infer` (besides `Option Strict`)

Comment: Use As Dynamic.

Comment: OR, you could keep Option Infer ON and cast the ExpandoObject to one of its underlying interfaces. It would be, e.g., `Dim li As List(Of ListItem) = items.Select(Function(item As IDictionary(Of String, Object)) New ListItem(item("Id"), item("Name"), item("Value"))).ToList()`

Comment: @DanielA.White can you show sample code??